# Export Google Drive document to LaTeX

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, latex, google-drive-api

Is there a way for exporting a document created in Google Drive to a .tex file?

I tried to use the .zip file that you can directly download from the Google Drive interface. That file contains the HTML version of the document and, as a first approach, I tried to transform that HTML document into a TEX file using the tools provided by www.w3.org ([enter link description here](http://www.w3.org/2004/04/xhlt91/)); however, the HTML file within the downloaded .zip is not XML well-formed and the elements of the lists are not nested, nesting level is distinguished by its class.

Therefore, is there a tool for directly exporting a Google Drive document into a TEX file?

Comment: Try tex.stackexchange.com. You might find some ideas there.

Comment: Thank you, I already try...